# Android: getSupportActionBar() always returns null in ActionBarSherlock library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to use the [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) library to provide backwards compatible ActionBar support with tabs in my Android app, so I downloaded the latest build, built the demo, and ran it.

If you go to Action Bar, then select Tab Navigation it crashes every time. Here's the stack trace:

```
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos/com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.app.ActionBarTabNavigation}: java.lang.NullPointerException  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.app.ActionBarTabNavigation.onCreate(ActionBarTabNavigation.java:19)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)  
09-03 02:34:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3078): ... 11 more
```

I can't move forward with my app until this is fixed. I wrote a bunch of code, set up the action bar in my app, and tried to run it, and it crashes with an NPE because of the null return value on the `getSupportActionBar()` call.

The relevant code is actually in the demo for the library:

```
public class ActionBarTabNavigation extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.newInstance(0))
            .commit();

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.newInstance(tab.getPosition()))
            .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to provide some code. `getSupportActionBar()` works in subclasses of `FragmentActivity`, at least after `super.onCreate()` is called.

Comment: Code added. The code is where it's crashing in the demo. The demo code is doing what you are saying, and it crashes with an NPE. It does the same thing in my app code, which is similar. What I'm saying is, the call to getSupportActionBar always returns null, in my code, and in the demo provided with the library. Perhaps you are using a different version? I grabbed the latest version late last night.

Comment: I'm using 3.1.3, downloaded as a zip from https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/zipball/3.1.3 and I do not get any crashes. If you downloaded from github, maybe there's a difference/bug. What version of the android SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm building against Android 3.2, which is required by the latest version of ActionBarSherlock. I'll try an earlier version of the latter and see if I have better luck.

Comment: I'm also using 3.1.3, as it turns out. The demo crashes when trying to use tabbed navigation.

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to either contact the developer, or just see what happens when you incorporate ABS into your project. I can confirm that `getSupportActionBar()` in 3.1.3 works for an tabbed activity that I have in my project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3143/discussion-between-jon-and-scienceprodigy)

Comment: did you set it out first?

  mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You should add the Sherlock theme to your application

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
```

Comment: I already had this as my theme, but I'll give you credit anyways. The real problem, I discovered, was that I was using Theme.NoTitleBar in the startup activity, which was the cause of the crash in my application. I'm not sure what is causing the crash in the ActionBarSherlock demo, but my app works now so I'm moving on.

Comment: I somehow managed to omit adding the theme: `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry I have the same mistake as you. Finally remove the Theme.NoTitleBar in Manifest and it works fine :D

Comment: android:debuggable="false" is best left unspecified

Answer (score 62):

I had the same problem on the Android ICS 4.0.4. I was using `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` on the FragmentActivity, but this was hiding the ActionBar on ICS+ devices that caused the `getSupportActionBar()` to be null.

Simply removed the:
`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

And it worked like a charm.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: but i need custom title,still getting np :(.

Answer (score 38):

Another reason this will happen on Honeycomb+ devices is because the `windowNoTitle` attribute is set in your style. Get rid of that as ActionBarSherlock will automatically remove it in pre-Honeycomb devices for you.

Comment: Yup that fixed it for me too :)

Comment: but i need custom title,still getting np :(.

Answer (score 15):

Another reason you might get null from `getSupportActionBar()` is trying to call it before `setContentView(R.layout.main)` or in your example adding a fragment.

I refactored oncreate and mistakenly put `getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 12):

Heres a funny one:
don't set the theme to -

```
    android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionbar"
```

Comment: I wasted hours on this, you are right, inside the manifest where the activity is declared, remove that line and it works.

Answer (score 6):

Another reason you might get null from `getSupportActionBar()` is when the activity is used in a TabHost on Honeycomb+.

Comment: This is my problem, any way to fix this?

Comment: @wasigh I don't know why you need it.. but you could try using Fragments instead of Actions, see [FragmentTabs.java](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java) or [FragmentTabsPager.java](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java). Install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragment to see how they work.

Comment: what about on pre honeycomb devices, im trying to use a tabhost with a fragmentActivity as one of the tabs and I'm getting null for getSupportActionBar();

Answer (score 5):

Depending how your write out code. ensure that you did set the toolbar first before calling it.

```
  mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

I just changed in Manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

to:

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and the error gone

Answer (score 1):

whenever we set customview using sherlock library. just remove this requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       like this we make customview using sherlock bar library..

```
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.header_sherlock_xmllayout);
    header_tvleft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_tvleft);
    header_tvleft.setText("Back");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after (sillily) forgetting to call the `super.onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

you are  declared Theme.Sherlock or Theme.Sherlock.Light as your activity or
application theme in the manifest Or using a custom theme that inherits
from one of these two

Example:-

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
```

also u can use dark theme:-

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to my activity in the Android Manifest file in an attempt to make it a dialogue activity. This too will remove the action bar hence a null pointer. Remove it or don't call `getSupportActioBar`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after adding a library to my project.  The remedy was to look in the library and remove any styles name "AppTheme" if you are using this same theme name in your manifest. There wasn't a conflict on my Galaxy S4, Jelly Bean, while there was a conflict on my Galaxy Tab.

Answer (score 0):

I make this mistake because i add the toobar in the fragment xml file. The code to find the toolbar in fragment is this:getActivity().findViewByid(id...),but my toolbar is in fragment xml file,so that there was no toolbar found and no toolbar beeing setSipprotActionBar() and also nothing get when getSupportActionBar().
So remember :**Do not put the toolbar in your fragment`s xml file.**