# ActionBar nullpointerException

Tags: java, android

I want to use ActionBarSherlock with my app. When I call `getSupportActionBar()` I get a `NullPointerException`; I already imported the ActionBarSherlock library into my project.

Here is my Java class:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends SherlockActivity  {


    @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
                com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = this.getSupportMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
                return true;
            }

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

                setContentView(R.layout.profile_page);



                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Example!");  //nullpointerException


              }
        }

}
```

And my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.sal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name=".FriendPickerApplication">



        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sal.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


              </activity>

         <!--  Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                  android:label="Register New Account"></activity>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" android:label="Profile page"></activity>

        <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="AIzaSyDTVRXMTmfe3jZyAlt-87kRgqM8y4TzIto"/>


        <activity android:name="SaleMapActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="GroupMapActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="DeliverMapActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="PickFriendsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="TabMainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="itemSaleActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="FreindsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="ExitActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="OneTimeDetailesScreen"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks.

and this is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>
```

adn here is the logcat:

```
03-24 16:20:24.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1927): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 16:20:24.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at com.example.sal.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:349)
03-24 16:20:24.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-24 16:20:24.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-24 16:20:24.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-24 16:20:24.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     ... 23 more
```

Comment: You need to include the output from your Logcat with the NullPointer exception.  Please post that.

Comment: hi, i added logcat, and i looked at this post however it doesnt help me

Comment: Please can you post also the class header?

Comment: i added it, to the main thread, my class extends the SherlockActivity

Comment: take a look on my post

Comment: Is `ProfileActivity` a separate activity, or is it being nested inside a `TabHost`?

Comment: the tabHost activity is start the profileActivity...

Comment: You cannot access the action bar from an activity in a `TabHost`. `TabHost` is designed for pre-HC devices; why are you using it?

Comment: i am using Tabs in the bottom, therefore it call first the Tabhost activity and then the profileActivity...

Answer (score 1):

Does your application theme extend the ABS theme?

For instance, as you specify:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Your style should be:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    ...
</style>
```

See also [this answer by Jake Wharton himself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7300887/154306).

Comment: hi, i cahnged my style( i also added it to the main thread:  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>    and it again give me nullpointerException

Comment: Perhaps you are changing the window decor to remove the title bar? By removing the title bar, there will be no action bar and hence it will return `null`.

Comment: as you can see from my activity, i dont remove the title bar...

Comment: `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` should not be needed; I would suggest removing that line.

Comment: i removed this line, however the actionbar still doesnt show for me..in the actionBar i only have the logo and the name of my application...

Comment: You can specify the display options using [setDisplayOptions()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions%28int%29), optionally using a mask. For instance, `setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE)`.

Comment: hi, i added this method, however it show me an error: "The method setDisplayOptions(int) is undefined for the type ProfileActivity", i need an Actionbar variale inorder to use this method, and as i said in the main Thread, when i want to get the actionbar varialbe it return null

Comment: Please consult the documentation. `setDisplayOptions()` is a method of `ActionBar`, not `Activity`.

Comment: hi,i need an Actionbar variable inorder to use this method, and as i said in the main Thread, when i want to get the actionbar varialbe it return null

Answer (score 1):

I cannot now explain why you are getting the NPE but please try this:

Instead of using

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Example!");  //nullpointerException
```

just use this

```
  setTitle("Example!");
```

Comment: hi, it doesnt solve my problem and also didnt even changed my title..as i wrote the actionbar still doesnt show for me..in the actionBar i only have the logo and the name of my application...

Comment: hi, i added this method, however it show me an error: "The method setDisplayOptions(int) is undefined for the type ProfileActivity"