# overflow actionbar menu android

Tags: java, android

i imported the library from here, inorder to use it as actionbar:

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

however i didnt find how can i implement a overflow menu item?

for example, in actionbarsherlock this code to implement the overflow menu item is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/root_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="More">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings_holo_light"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="About"/>
   </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

can someone help me with it? maybe the developer of this code can help me?

thanks alot

Comment: Pretty sure you can't, you can always change it yourself. Why not use Actionbarsherlock or support library instead?

Comment: because i found this library much easier than actionbarsherlock, which reutrn null for me when i called the method, as i mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600783/actionbar-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

same way you can implement system actionbar menu. no need to use any lib or other just use this code for your menu and it will work for you and for generating your menu use oncreateoptionmenu/onprepareoptionmenu for example using with this code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/root_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="More">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings_holo_light"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="About"/>
   </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

now inflate this menu in your activity/fragementactivity using oncreateoptionmenu/onprepareoptionmenu

here is the using of action menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Toast.makeText(context,"Setting menu selected",Toast.SHORT_LENGTH).show();
        break;      
    case R.id.menu_about:
        Toast.makeText(context,"About menu selected",Toast.SHORT_LENGTH).show();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: hi, how can i determine the action when pressing the submenu item?

Comment: thanks alot, also, do i need to write code in the OnCreate method? because i have some problem as i mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600783/actionbar-nullpointerexception   do i must to write something in the onCreate method? thanks alot