# getSupportActionBar() returns null

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I'm learning to use slidingmenu library. So far, I could use viewpager with 2 fragment. But I cannot use actionbar tab to navigate these fragments. 
Here is my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    mPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyViewPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager()));
    setContentView(mPager);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(
                        SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
                break;
            default:
                getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(
                        SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
                break;
            }
        }

    });
    mPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    // Construct tab for action bar
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub } }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    tab1 = mActionBar.newTab();
    suntime.setText("Sun Time");
    suntime.setTabListener(tabListener);

    tab2= mActionBar.newTab();
    mapview.setText("View Map");
    mapview.setTabListener(tabListener);

    mActionBar.addTab(tab1);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab2);
}
```

I encounter getSupportActionBar() null exception errors.
Anyone can help?

Comment: I can not find where you do use getSupportActionBar

Comment: Are you using Theme with actionbar?

Comment: @blackbelt: in my code there is statement `mActionbar = getSupportActionBar`

Comment: It might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294797/android-getsupportactionbar-always-returns-null-in-actionbarsherlock-library?rq=1

Comment: @Lingviston I use `Theme.Sherlock`, I got no problems with theme issue :(

Comment: "in my code there is statement 'mActionbar = getSupportActionBar' " -- there is no such statement in the code that you have listed here.

Comment: @TruongThanhDung the firefox "find" feature can not find that statment

Comment: @lifus I read it b4 posting new question :( but no luck for me

Comment: @Lingviston I stripped the code, sorry about that, I will update in a moment

Comment: @TruongThanhDung Please add a stacktrace.

Comment: Also include `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Check that you're using SherlockActivity class/sbclass.

Comment: @ALL Thanks guys, I sorted it out. I **mistakenly** `import android.app.ActionBar` instead of `import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar`. Now it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

@ALL Thanks guys, I sorted it out. I mistakenly `import android.app.ActionBar` instead of `import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar`. Now it worked perfectly :)