# getSupportActionBar() of SherlockActivity returns null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbaractivity

I am trying to use `Sherlock ActionBar` by extending my `Activity` to `Sherlock Activity` but I am receiving the following error on `getSupportActionBar()` which return `null`.

```
05-16 10:45:22.537: E/AndroidRuntime(20631): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tzoomers.birthdaysdiary/com.tzoomers.birthdaysdiary.SyncActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 10:45:22.537: E/AndroidRuntime(20631):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
05-16 10:45:22.537: E/AndroidRuntime(20631):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1991)
05-16 10:45:22.537: E/AndroidRuntime(20631):    at 
.
.
..

05-16 10:45:22.537: E/AndroidRuntime(20631): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 10:45:22.537: E/AndroidRuntime(20631):    at com.tzoomers.birthdaysdiary.SyncActivity.onCreate(SyncActivity.java:38)
05-16 10:45:22.537: E/AndroidRuntime(20631):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
05-16 10:45:22.537: E/AndroidRuntime(20631):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
```

I am setting the `App Theme` to `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"`. Can anyone please tell me why i am getting `NullPointerException` on `getSupportActionBar()` in `SherlockActivity`?

Activity is :

```
package com.tzoomers.birthdaysdiary;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.tzoomers.controller.BirthdaysClickOListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SyncActivity extends SherlockActivity{
    Button importFromFacebookButton, sendToDeviceButton, receiveFromDeviceButton, saveToSdCardButton, loadFromSDCardButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_sync_activity);

//      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        importFromFacebookButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.importFacebookButton);
        sendToDeviceButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendToDeviceButton);
        receiveFromDeviceButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.receiveFromDeviceButton);

        importFromFacebookButton.setOnClickListener(
                new BirthdaysClickOListener(ActionType.IMPORT_FACEBOOK_CONTACTS, this));
        sendToDeviceButton.setOnClickListener(
                new BirthdaysClickOListener(ActionType.SEND_TO_DEVICE, this));
        receiveFromDeviceButton.setOnClickListener(
                new BirthdaysClickOListener(ActionType.RECEIVE_FROM_DEVICE, this));

//      getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//      getSupportActionBar().se
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
            com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public enum ActionType
    {
        IMPORT_FACEBOOK_CONTACTS, SEND_TO_DEVICE, RECEIVE_FROM_DEVICE, SAVE_TO_SDCARD, LOAD_FROM_SDCARD
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: @PratikButani: `Activity` added.

Comment: No. I am not receiving error after the removal of `getSupportactionBar()`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7300887/1318946

Comment: I have already set that to `Theme.Sherlock` but still getting the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: getSupportActionBar() always returns null in ActionBarSherlock library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294797/android-getsupportactionbar-always-returns-null-in-actionbarsherlock-library)

Comment: i have tried that. My `android os version is 4.0` i have set `minSDK=9 and targetSDK=19` and `Theme` to `Theme.Sherlock`