# How to override the style.Getting null pointer exception getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Using sherlok in my project.

I am getting null pointer exception for this line getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true).

We have override the style because in all activity we don't wan't title bar.for that we have used our custom style and in parent we have given reference of @style/Theme.Sherlock. and we are using this customg style in my manifest file..

If I used  android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" > then it works fine for me.

if i put requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in all activity then it works but i want some generic solution and why above thing is not working.

logcat:

```
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.imlee.mobile/com.imlee.mobile.ImleeMasterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at com.imlee.mobile.ImleeMasterActivity.onCreate(ImleeMasterActivity.java:65)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
06-20 12:08:56.172: E/AndroidRuntime(12172):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The Android ICS 4.0.4. I was using `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` on the FragmentActivity, but this was hiding the ActionBar on ICS+ devices that caused the getSupportActionBar() to be null.

Simply removed the:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Another reason this will happen on Honeycomb+ devices is because the windowNoTitle attribute is set in your style. Get rid of that as ActionBarSherlock will automatically remove it in pre-Honeycomb devices for you.

see below link for more detail:-

[Android: getSupportActionBar() always returns null in ActionBarSherlock library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294797/android-getsupportactionbar-always-returns-null-in-actionbarsherlock-library)

Comment: But I have 20 activities and 5 fragment on fragement i want action bar and in activity i don't want action bar. So i have to add in 20 activity i should add feature_no_title line. is there any alternative.why style is not override.