# RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.PropertiesActivity}

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I tried to put Example project of slidemenu in new project .everything is fine and app started 
after i touched one of the item in main activity app crashed
here codes

```
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newtest/com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.example.PropertiesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.example.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:54)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.example.PropertiesActivity.onCreate(PropertiesActivity.java:25)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
01-02 00:56:10.139: E/AndroidRuntime(28905):    ... 11 more
```

PropertiesActivity:

```
package com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.newtest.R;

public class PropertiesActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public PropertiesActivity() {
        super(R.string.properties);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.properties);

        // left and right modes
        RadioGroup mode = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.mode);
        mode.check(R.id.left);
        mode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.left:
                    sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
                    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
                    break;
                case R.id.right:
                    sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
                    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
                    break;
                case R.id.left_right:
                    sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
                    sm.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SampleListFragment())
                    .commit();                  
                    sm.setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
                    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
                }
            }           
        });

        // touch mode stuff
        RadioGroup touchAbove = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.touch_above);
        touchAbove.check(R.id.touch_above_full);
        touchAbove.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.touch_above_full:
                    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
                    break;
                case R.id.touch_above_margin:
                    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
                    break;
                case R.id.touch_above_none:
                    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        // scroll scale stuff
        SeekBar scrollScale = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.scroll_scale);
        scrollScale.setMax(1000);
        scrollScale.setProgress(333);
        scrollScale.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) { }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                getSlidingMenu().setBehindScrollScale((float) seekBar.getProgress()/seekBar.getMax());
            }
        });


        // behind width stuff
        SeekBar behindWidth = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.behind_width);
        behindWidth.setMax(1000);
        behindWidth.setProgress(750);
        behindWidth.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) { }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                float percent = (float) seekBar.getProgress()/seekBar.getMax();
                getSlidingMenu().setBehindWidth((int) (percent * getSlidingMenu().getWidth()));
                getSlidingMenu().requestLayout();
            }
        });

        // shadow stuff
        CheckBox shadowEnabled = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.shadow_enabled);
        shadowEnabled.setChecked(true);
        shadowEnabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked)
                    getSlidingMenu().setShadowDrawable(
                            getSlidingMenu().getMode() == SlidingMenu.LEFT ? 
                                    R.drawable.shadow : R.drawable.shadowright);
                else
                    getSlidingMenu().setShadowDrawable(null);
            }
        });
        SeekBar shadowWidth = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.shadow_width);
        shadowWidth.setMax(1000);
        shadowWidth.setProgress(75);
        shadowWidth.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) { }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                float percent = (float) seekBar.getProgress()/ (float) seekBar.getMax();
                int width = (int) (percent * (float) getSlidingMenu().getWidth());
                getSlidingMenu().setShadowWidth(width);
                getSlidingMenu().invalidate();
            }
        });

        // fading stuff
        CheckBox fadeEnabled = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.fade_enabled);
        fadeEnabled.setChecked(true);
        fadeEnabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                getSlidingMenu().setFadeEnabled(isChecked);
            }           
        });
        SeekBar fadeDeg = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.fade_degree);
        fadeDeg.setMax(1000);
        fadeDeg.setProgress(666);
        fadeDeg.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) { }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                getSlidingMenu().setFadeDegree((float) seekBar.getProgress()/seekBar.getMax());
            }           
        });
    }

}
```

BaseActivity:

```
package com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity;
import com.newtest.R;

public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    private int mTitleRes;
    protected ListFragment mFrag;

    public BaseActivity(int titleRes) {
        mTitleRes = titleRes;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle(mTitleRes);

        // set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFrag = new SampleListFragment();
            t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
            t.commit();
        } else {
            mFrag = (ListFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame);
        }

        // customize the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggle();
            return true;
        case R.id.github:
            Util.goToGitHub(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

can't find the problem please help me

Comment: where is a code ?BaseActivity class code please

Comment: @IceJOKER sorry, here is the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the Sherlock theme to your application

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
```

Comment: @newuser you're welcome ) just use the google - it's realy helpful tool ))

Comment: YEAP i tried but none of the heats were related to my problem

Comment: @newuser what about it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294797/android-getsupportactionbar-always-returns-null-in-actionbarsherlock-library ? i just search "getsupportactionbar null" and first link in reslut is stackoverflow post link ))

Comment: @ IceJOKER sure you did , i tried the error from stack trace not "getsupportactionbar null" . you have more experience.